# Get method for two variables

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

For some reason the paging does not work with the search get that I have although it was working fine in pages that don't use the get method. If I search for a term lets say example and I have eleven titles in the database that have in their title the word example 10 the first 10 should appear and then in the second page I should have the eleventh one. However when I try to go to the second page the search get from the first page is lost and I get ?pn=$i

```
<form class="sea" action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input class="searchbar" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <button class="searchbutton" name="submit-search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit-search'])) {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['search']);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM video_games WHERE video_games_title LIKE '%$search%' OR video_games_genre LIKE '$search'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $rows = $row[0];
    $page_rows = 10;
    $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
    if($last < 1){
        $last = 1;
    }
    $pagenum = 1;
    if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
        $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
     }
    if ($pagenum < 1) {
        $pagenum = 1;
    }else if ($pagenum > $last) {
       $pagenum = $last;
   }
   $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM video_games WHERE video_games_title LIKE '%$search%' OR video_games_genre LIKE '$search' ORDER BY video_games_id $limit ";
   $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($query);
   $paginationCtrls = '';
   if($last != 1){
       if ($pagenum > 1) {
           $previous = $pagenum - 1;
           $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
           for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
               if($i > 0){
                   $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
               }
           }
       }
       $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
       for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
           $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
           if($i >= $pagenum+4){
               break;
           }
       } 
       if ($pagenum != $last) {
           $next = $pagenum + 1;
           $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> ';
       }
   }
   if ($queryResult > 0) {
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
           $id = $row["video_games_id"];
           $title = $row["video_games_title"];
           $genre = $row["video_games_genre"];
           $image = $row["video_games_image"];
           $description= $row["video_games_description"];
           $platform= $row["video_games_platform"];
           $price= $row["video_games_price"];
?>
//Putting the data from the database to the html
<?php }//end of while ?>
<div id="pagination_controls"><?php echo $paginationCtrls; ?></div>
```

If I do some replacements

```
$paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?search='.$search.'&submit-search='.'?pn='.$i.'"">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
```

When I press the second page I get the results from the first and the $paginationCtrls also say that I am in the first page eventhough in the url says search=example&submit-search=?pn=2
Why is it not working have I messed with the syntax somwhere?
What can I do to fix it?

Comment: In your second example, `?pn` should be `&pn`.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks man that solved it I didn't realise it had to be looking back it makes sense

Comment: Welcome.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @PatrickQ sorry give me some time to find how to do that I am new to this